# Android: AsyncTask: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have two threads running where I'm trying to send some data to server (I'm using Java Tomcat server) using AsyncTask. I am using Java observable class to notify the server whenever any new data is observed. One of my execution is done like following (It's receiving some wifi values and sending it to server) - 
`new ServerCommunicationTaskWifi(textView, MyMessage.SENDER_VALUE_WIFI).execute(rssi, bssid, distance, time);`

But everytime, during runtime I'm receiving the following exception - 
`java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`

Any suggestion please?